# boost::asio: How to detect that the receiver socket is closed in async_write handler?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The implementation:

The client uses async_write to sending messages to the server. In the write handler, it starts next async_write operation.

The server uses async_read to receive messages from the client. In the read handler, it starts next async_read operation.

I want to stop the async operation immediately when the remote side is closed.

When I close the client, the async_read calls the handler immediately with an boost::asio::error::eof error code. But when the server is closed, the client continues writing. How can I make it call the handler with an error code?

Comment: You can't, because you don't know immediately. The only way you can detect it is by doing a write, and you will almost certainly only detect it on a *subsequent* write.

Comment: If the socket is closed then async_read will instantly return with an error. As long as you are polling async_read and check error then you shouldn't need to worry about async_write failing.

Comment: @user207421 yes, I actually did the write. The return value in the write handler indicates that I successfully transferred the whole message and didn't get an error. I think the message is written to a buffer or something. What does 'detect it by doing a write' mean?

Comment: @Nina The error in async_read is what I want, but I also want to let the writing side know the closing event and do something(such as clear the message queue)

Comment: Asnyc_write will also return to the callback with an error if the socket is closed. But typically you just handle the error in the async_read callback. From there you can clear your write queue because your async_write will also have returned.

Comment: Sorry, 'the async_write calls the handler immediately' should be 'the async_read calls the handler immediately'. It has been fixed

Comment: The client shouldn't continue writing... If async_read returns with an error then use some indicator like bool socketclosed = true, to prevent the writing from occurring again. You have full control of your read and write operation, so the fact that you're telling it to continue writing is completely your intention and your fault...so stop making it write it will not write on its own. Also you should only perform ONE write operation at a time(per socket) and write again when the other one returns.

Comment: @Nina Do you mean The async_write will return immediately when I close the socket at the reading side? That's what I did but the async_write didn't return and kept writing. I've called socket.shutdown before socket.close.

Comment: It's because you're probably calling multiple async_write operations on a single socket before a previous call returns. Which you should not do.

Comment: @Nina Yes, I just want to tell the sender to stop in a graceful way. I want to receive a FIN or an EOF when the other side is closed. How can I do it?

Comment: The remote side needs to close the socket properly using `shutdown()`, then the async send() will return a socket closed error. But even if you simply close the socket, the next write will fail with a connection reset error.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms your design should look like this:

`Call async_read`

When you need to write

`Call async_write`

Do not call async_write again until the previous async_write call has returned.
If you need to call multiple async_write operations, then que your buffers.

```
Call async_write
callback pull next buffer from que
Call async_write
callback pull next buffer from que
Call async_write
callback pull next buffer from que
```

By doing this, you're ensuring this only one async_write operating is in effect at all times per socket. Which is how it should be.
Do NOT do this.

```
Call async_write
Call async_write
Call async_write
callback
callback
callback
```

This is where you run into issues by trying to stop async_write after a read operation has occurred with an error.
When async_read returns with an error you no longer have to take extra steps in your async_write operation to cancel concurrent calls.

```
Call async_read
Call async_write
async_read callback returns with error (do not call async_read again)
async_write returns with error (do not call async_write again)
```

So when calling async_write check a flag (iswriting) if the flag is true, then push your buffer into your que. When the callback returns, check your que, pull the next buffer and call async_write again. If iswriting is false, then just call async_write instead of pushing it to the que. If your callback returns and your que is finally empty then set iswriting to false again.

This is all pretty straight forward...

Comment: You didn't post your code so I can assume you're calling async_write wrong. Because it should return. According to boost's documentation: "This function is used to asynchronously write a certain number of bytes of data to a stream. The function call always returns immediately. The asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following conditions is true:

All of the data in the supplied buffers has been written. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
An error occurred."

Comment: I've found that the first async_write request submitted after the closing event at the reading side is done well. The argument indicating the bytes transferred in the write handle is what I've sent. But the next request failed with an error code "broken pipe".  I think that's because a buffer is used in the writing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You read/write, in other words you have a protocol, so add a new flag (message, bit ...) saying that you will close the socket, and close the socket only when that message has been received.
Of course your protocol must handle errors.